# Selecting related pairs LINQ

Tags: linq, select, datatable

I'm using LINQ to manipulate a datatable. I have 3 columns - I would like group by one and then select the remaining 2 columns together. At the moment I have something like this

```
var query = reportDataTable.AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(c => c["Code"])
            .Select(g => 
                   new { 
                    Code = g.Key, 
                    Rank = g.Select(f => new 
                                       { f["rank"], 
                                         f["Name"]}).ToArray() 
                   });
```

but I get issues due to anonymous types. I know this syntax would work if I could reference the the column headers directly (in say a list or w/e). How can I get around this with DataTables? Cheers.

Edit:

Well I'd like to be able to reference the fields later when I come to populate the data into a different datatable:

```
            foreach (var q in query)
        {
            DataRow df = dp.NewRow();
            df["Code"] = q.Code;

            foreach (var rank in q.Rank)
            {
               df[rank.name] = rank.rank;
            }
            dp.Rows.Add(df);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define your `Rank` fields, Also if you have a class for it, call related class constructor,
you can see this in bellow code, before `ToArray`.

```
var query = reportDataTable.AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(c => c["Code"])
            .Select(g => 
              new { Code = g.Key, Rank = 
                     g.Select(f => new { rank = f["rank"], name = f["Name"]})
              .ToArray() });
```

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5441/discussion-between-saeed-amiri-and-oded)

Comment: I'm a little confused - the tuple suggestion has disappeared so I guess that's not the way to go? Trying Saeeds method works in the query, but throws an error when trying to reference via rank.name in the 2nd loop. What am I missing? Cheers.

Comment: @Sufo, You say you get compile error? or runtime error? and what is exact error description?

Comment: compilation: `the best overloaded method match for "System.Data.DataRow.this[System.Data.DataColumn]" has some invalid arguments`

Comment: Hi, the solution to this was to cast the types `rank = (Int64)f["rank"], name = (string)f["Name"]` Thanks for your help with the original response - I can't believe I didn't try that myself :)